# How to set cell color in TableLayoutPanel dynamically?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I need to write a function which will set the color in `TableLayoutPanel` cells depending on some condition during running the program.

`TableLayoutPanel` is divided by 16x16. There is some condition at the start of the program. If the condition is true for a cell this sell must be painted blue color. For example:

```
private void start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (string str in some_list)
    {
       if (some condition)
       {
           set_color_in_cell at row[i] colum[j] //(what shoud i use here?)
       }
    }
}
```

I found such example:

```
private void tableLayoutPanel_CellPaint(object sender, TableLayoutCellPaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row == 0 && e.Column == 1)
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Black), e.CellBounds);
    }
}
```

But I don't understand how to use it. If somebody knows about this please help me.

```
private void start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string SyncAnswer = "";
    foreach (string file_string in Data_from_file)
    {
       COM_Port.WriteLine(file_string);
       while (SyncAnswer != "READY")
       {
           SyncAnswer = COM_Port.ReadLine();
           if (SyncAnswer.Substring(0, 4) == "Fire")
           {
              //raise event
              //paint for example a cell in Row=i Colum=j
           }
           else if (SyncAnswer.Substring(0, 4) == "Skip")
          {
             //raise event
          }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Assign `tableLayoutPanel_CellPaint` to `CellPaint` event of your `tableLayoutPanel` and then paint based on some criteria. `e.Row` is the row index, `e.Column` is column index of the cell. `e.CellBounds` is bound of the cell.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not good at programming. Could you please clarify what exactly do you mean by adding an example?

Comment: You can use CellPaint event or you can simply put panels in cells and change the BackColor of panels. See the answer below.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

### Option 1 - Using [CellPaint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.cellpaint?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) Event

Here is a step by step example:

1. Create a `Form`
2. Put a [`TableLayoutPanel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/tablelayoutpanel-control-overview?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) from toolbox on your `Form`
3. Select `tableLayoutPanel1` on design surface and Press <kbd>F4</kbd> Key to see properties.
4. From toolbar of property grid, you can select to show Properties <kbd>[image]</kbd> or Events <kbd>[image]</kbd>. Click on events icon and from the list, double click on [`CellPaint`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.cellpaint?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) event to create `tableLayoutPanel1_CellPaint` event handler in code.
5. You can paint each cells background in this method based on some criteria. The event will raise for painting each cells background and `e.Row` is the row index, `e.Column` is column index and `e.CellBounds` is bound of the painting cell.

For example in below sample, we draw black background `if ((e.Column + e.Row) % 2 == 1)` otherwise, we draw white background:

```
private void tableLayoutPanel1_CellPaint(object sender, TableLayoutCellPaintEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.Column + e.Row) % 2 == 1)
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, e.CellBounds);
    else
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, e.CellBounds);
}
```

[image]

**To change Color Dynamically**

To change the color from another point of program, for example in a `Click` event of a button, you should store back colors of each cell in an 2-dimension array and use that color to create a brush for that cell:

Define `bgColors` in your form:

```
Color[,] bgColors = new Color[2, 2] {
    { SystemColors.Control, SystemColors.Control }, 
    { SystemColors.Control, SystemColors.Control } 
};
```

Draw background of cells this way:

```
private void tableLayoutPanel1_CellPaint(object sender, TableLayoutCellPaintEventArgs e)
{
    using (var b = new SolidBrush(bgColors[e.Column, e.Row]))
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(b , e.CellBounds);
    }
}
```

To change the `BackColor` of a `Cell` you can:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //column: 0 ,row: 1
    bgColors[0, 1] = Color.Red;
    tableLayoutPanel1.Refresh();
}
```

---

### Option 2 - Hosting Panel in Cells

As another simple option, you can put `Panel` in each cell, and set the `Dock` property of `Panel` to `Fill` and set its `Margin` property to `0,0`, then each time you want to change color of a panel at position `(column, row)` you can use this code:

```
this.tableLayoutPanel1.GetControlFromPosition(column, row).BackColor = Color.Red;
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks so much. But the point is that this event raise up only at the start of the program. I have to do such way at which the event will raise up only when it is needed over and over again.

Comment: I added a piece of code from my program to clarify what i mean

Comment: No, the event raises when the `TableLayoutPanel` needs painting (for example after restoring window, or after another form move above it or after you manually call `tableLayoutPanel1.Refresh() or .Invalidate()`

Comment: As another simple option, you can put `Panel` in each cell, and set the `Dock` property of `Panel` to `Fill` and set its `Margin` property to `0,0`, then each time you want to change color of a panel at position `(column, row)` you can use this code: `this.tableLayoutPanel1.GetControlFromPosition(column, row).BackColor = Color.Red;`

Comment: No problem) it's not difficult for me

Comment: Thank you for your feedback :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way that is pretty simple is to dynamically add multiple PictureBox controls (ex: pbCellColor below) to you cells in your TableLayoutPanel, or some other more simple simple control, dock it, set the margin to
zero, then whenever you want:

```
pbCellColor.Dock = DockStyle.None;
pbCellColor.Margin = new Size(0, 0, 0, 0);
pbCellColor.Backcolor = Color.Red;
```

[image: TableLayoutPanel with PictureBox to color cell]

Easy, no event handling or state checks. Just set it and forget it. Worst case, if you call from a non-gui thread, you will need to Invoke the action.