# Changing Cells of TableLayoutPanel (background color/image)?

Tags: c#, tablelayoutpanel

I want to add an image inside a cell of TableLayoutPanel from Properties.Resource.image directly :

```
tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(Properties.Resource.image,column,row);
//cell background should be covered with image
```

I'd also like to change the cell's background color simple style :

```
tableLayoutPanel1.Position(column,row).backroundcolor=Color.Red;
```

I tried the following solution, but this did not work in my case :

[How to set cell color in TableLayoutPanel dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34064499/how-to-set-cell-color-in-tablelayoutpanel-dynamically/34088085)

How can I update the background image and color correctly while using TableLayoutPanel?

Comment: `tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add` expects a control.

Comment: How i can fix its problem ?

Comment: Use a control that can show an image, like a PictureBox.

Comment: Can u show ,how i can do?

Comment: At design time, drop a `PictureBox` into a cell, set it's `Dock` property to `Fill`, and examine the other properties of the picture box. Especially the `BackColor`, `Image`, `SizeMode`, `BackgroundImage`, and `BackgroundImageLayout`.